# How can I delegate 'change' event on input element from body?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, event-delegation

I know already about event delegation by jQuery.
However, How can I do same thing with pure Javascript without jQuery.

Although I attached `change` event on body or the top element(div), `change` event is not triggered when value of input element in body or top element is changed...

How can I do this?

Comment: That means, Do I attach event on each input element in body?..
So that, I think performance issue can be occured... hmm

Comment: Ahhm, sorry, I really missed the part in the second to last line about inputs

Comment: So, yes, it does work if you have inputs, selects or textareas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tl;DR:** you probably need to listen on the **input** event instead.

---

The reason you are probably not seeing the event being triggered, is because it is triggered:  *"...when the element loses focus after its value was changed."* [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

What you probably need to listen to, is the `input` event instead which *"fires when the value has been changed."* [Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event)

Here's an event listener attached to the `<body>` HTML element which captures all the 'bubbled' `input` and `change` events *(see how the `input` event is triggered immediately whereas the `change` event requires that the input element loses focus, e.g. when pressing Tab)*:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Input Event Delegation</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input name="email" type="email" />
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <script>
      document.body.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
        console.log("type:", e.type, "value:", e.target.value);
      });
      document.body.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
        console.log("type:", e.type, "value:", e.target.value);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just listen for the event on one element (in this case `elSelector`) and then only execute the event when the actual target fits a `selector` in that element.

```
function on(elSelector, eventName, selector, fn) {
    var element = document.querySelector(elSelector);

    element.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
        var possibleTargets = element.querySelectorAll(selector);
        var target = event.target;

        for (var i = 0, l = possibleTargets.length; i < l; i++) {
            var el = target;
            var p = possibleTargets[i];

            while(el && el !== element) {
                if (el === p) {
                    return fn.call(p, event);
                }

                el = el.parentNode;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

In the example below you can see that it also works with dynamic elements!

```js
on("#inputs", "change", ".event", (target, evt) => console.log(target.target));




function on(elSelector, eventName, selector, fn) {
  var element = document.querySelector(elSelector);

  element.addEventListener(eventName, function(event) {
    var possibleTargets = element.querySelectorAll(selector);
    var target = event.target;

    for (var i = 0, l = possibleTargets.length; i < l; i++) {
      var el = target;
      var p = possibleTargets[i];

      while (el && el !== element) {
        if (el === p) {
          return fn.call(p, event);
        }

        el = el.parentNode;
      }
    }
  });
}

/** random code for the button to add more inputs **/

let i = 7;

document.querySelector("#b").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector("#inputs").innerHTML += i + ` <input type="text" class="event"> <br>`;
  i++;
});
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
  1 <input type="text" class="event"> <br>
  2 <input type="text" class=""> <br>
  3 <input type="text" class="event"> <br>
  4 <input type="text" class=""> <br>
  5 <input type="text" class="event"> <br>
  6 <input type="text" class=""> <br>
</div>

<br><br>
<button id="b">Add another input</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define your event `function`:

```
function(event) doSomething{
    //Your code
}
```

Let's get all the `input` tags inside your `body`:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

Now, let's iterate them and attach the event:

```
for (var inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputs.length; inputIndex++) {
    inputs.addEventListener('change', doSomething);
}
```

Comment: However, If some input elements are created dynamically, those input elements can not listen 'change' event.

Comment: @YounghunJung you can achieve that by listening to the DOMSubtreeModified event and handle the changes accordingly, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMSubtreeModified

Comment: @YounghunJung or you can use the MutationObserver API for this purpose, see here: https://davidwalsh.name/detect-node-insertion